# Process: 50680 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx2048m -Dmidpoint.home=/opt/midpoint/var -jar /opt/midpoint/lib/midpoint.jar (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, service, java-17

[followed this url for the service creation](https://docs.evolveum.com/midpoint/install/systemd/)

systemctl status midpoint.service

```
● midpoint.service - MidPoint Standalone Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/midpoint.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-01-02 07:15:43 UTC; 1h 55min ago
    Process: 2005 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xmx2048m -Dmidpoint.home=/opt/midpoint/var -jar /opt/midpoint/lib/mi>
   Main PID: 2005 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 7.099s

Jan 02 07:15:43 midpoint-java-19 java[2005]:                 at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.Spring>
Jan 02 07:15:43 midpoint-java-19 java[2005]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurato>
Jan 02 07:15:43 midpoint-java-19 java[2005]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurato>
Jan 02 07:15:43 midpoint-java-19 java[2005]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurato>
Jan 02 07:15:43 midpoint-java-19 java[2005]:                 at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.Logbac>
Jan 02 07:15:43 midpoint-java-19 java[2005]:                 at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.Logbac>
Jan 02 07:15:43 midpoint-java-19 java[2005]:                 ... 30 more
Jan 02 07:15:43 midpoint-java-19 systemd[1]: midpoint.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILU>
Jan 02 07:15:43 midpoint-java-19 systemd[1]: midpoint.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 02 07:15:43 midpoint-java-19 systemd[1]: midpoint.service: Consumed 7.099s CPU time.
~
```

when I am running the start.sh file the application running succesfully

start.sh content

```
root@midpoint-java-19:/usr/bin# cat /opt/midpoint/bin/start.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Copyright (C) 2017-2020 Evolveum and contributors
#
# This work is dual-licensed under the Apache License 2.0
# and European Union Public License. See LICENSE file for details.

set -eu

SCRIPT_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd -P)
EXECUTABLE=midpoint.sh

if [[ ! -x "${SCRIPT_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE}" ]]; then
  echo "Cannot find ${SCRIPT_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE}"
  echo "The file is absent or does not have execute permission"
  echo "This file is needed to run this program"
  exit 1
fi

exec "${SCRIPT_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE}" start "$@"
```

when I am checking the logs using jounalctl -u midpoint -n 20 for the last 20 numbers of logs

```
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:26)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:206)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:126)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:104)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.postHandle(AppenderModelHandler.java:84)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:257)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.traversalLoop(DefaultProcessor.java:90)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:106)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:208)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator.processModel(SpringBootJoranCo>
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:170)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.configureByResourceUrl(LogbackLogging>
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSyste>
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint java[51303]:                 ... 32 more
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint systemd[1]: midpoint.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint systemd[1]: midpoint.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 01 12:38:54 midpoint systemd[1]: midpoint.service: Consumed 7.904s CPU time.
```

Comment: Check the full log with `journalctl -u midpoint` (off the top of my head, I'm not on a linux machine to verify currently) and add it to the question

Comment: hi @FedericoklezCulloca thanks for your effort, added the logs to the question

Comment: We'll need the full log, not just the last 20 lines. It's displaying a stack trace, but we'll need to see it in full.

Comment: hey @FedericoklezCulloca thanks for your suggestion, it got resolved by checking the each logs. had permission issue of the multiple directory in midpoint application files directory.